# catboost data visualization is not displayed

Tags: jupyter-notebook, catboost

I'm trying to use the data visualization feature in catboost - the one that visualizes training vs validation error (learning curve):

`model.fit(X_train, y_train,cat_features=categorical_features_indices,eval_set=(X_val, y_val),verbose=False,plot=True)`

I defined in fit method `plot = True` but no plot has shown up.

I also tried running the Catboost documentation example: https://catboost.ai/docs/features/visualization_jupyter-notebook.html#visualization_jupyter-notebook but it doesn't work either.

I'm using Jupyter notebook in Chrome.